# How to prove this formula. Formula is for evaluate limits which answers are e to the power something.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, theorem-provers

I would like to ask you about how to prove this formula.
I come up with this formula when i was browsing internet.
It works when i used it on given examples, but i would like to know if it works in general and how to prove it.
The formula is 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)^{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{g(x)\cdot(f(x)-1)}$$
Consider f is polynomial function of first degree.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Comparison with the correct substitution $(f(x))^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\ln f(x)}$ would suggest the answer to be "NO".

Comment: But when i use it the answer is always right how is that possible. :)

Comment: Have you tried to find a case where $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)\ln f(x)\ne \lim_{x\to\infty}g(x) (f(x)-1)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

This formula is true **Only when $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1 \space \& \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \to \infty$$**

**Proof:**

let $$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)^{g(x)}$$
Taking log on both sides, we get $$log(L) = \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \space log(f(x))$$
now, since $\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{log(1+a)}{a}=1$, if we substitute $1+a$ as $f(x)$, the limit changes to $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{log(f(x))}{f(x)-1}=1$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty} log(f(x)) = f(x)-1$

substituting the above result in the expression for $log(L)$, we obtain 
$$ log(L) = \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \cdot (f(x)-1)$$

On taking an exponent both sides and removing the log, we get 
$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\space g(x) \cdot (f(x)-1)}$$
which is the required result

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally true:

Take $f \equiv2$ and $g \equiv3$ the left side is equal $8$, the right side is equal $e^3$.

Comment: Ok but when it is function f is like $(x-2)/(x+5)$ it works

Comment: Lacking assumptions about functions, start by assuming they are degree 1 polynomials for example.